# Function binding in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science, higher-order-functions

```
n = 7

def f(x):
    n = 8
    return x + 1

def g(x):
    n = 9
    def h():
        return x + 1
    return h

def f(f, x):
    return f(x + n)

f = f(g, n)
g = (lambda y: y())(f)
```

I'm trying to understand and keep track of all the changes in the binding of functions, but cannot seem to grasp why the y parameter in the lambda function gets binded to h() on being called.

The transition from step 14-15 in this [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/composingprograms.html#code=n%20%3D%207%0A%0Adef%20f%28x%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20n%20%3D%208%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x%20%2B%201%0A%0Adef%20g%28x%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20n%20%3D%209%0A%20%20%20%20def%20h%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20x%20%2B%201%0A%20%20%20%20return%20h%0A%0Adef%20f%28f,%20x%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%28x%20%2B%20n%29%0A%0Af%20%3D%20f%28g,%20n%29%0Ag%20%3D%20%28lambda%20y%3A%20y%28%29%29%28f%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=14&mode=display&origin=composingprograms.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D) link to be precise

Comment: You understand that your first `def f(x)` is being overwritten by `def f(f, x): ...` correct? Also, it is really confusing to use a parameter name that is the same as the function name

Comment: In any case, `f = f(g, n)` (again, very confusing naming going on) basically translates to `f = g(14)` which will return `def h` closed over `x == 14`.  And `(lambda y: y())(f)` is just a rediculous way of writing `f()`, so then `g = h()` which is simply `g = 14 + 1`

Comment: That's the point actually, the question wants me to keep track of all the changes in these bindings intentionally to differentiate intrinsic functions from their names. The issue is just about what I posted

Comment: OK well, did you read my second comment? Again, keep in mind, `g = (lambda y: y())(f)` is just a stupid way of writing `g = f()`

Comment: Python executes the program linealy from top to bottom. Grab a pencil and a piece of paper and follow the program. Remember to keep the names of the functions and the functions separated.

Comment: This could easily be made even more confusing. Why not have `h` defined with `def h(n=f): n(x)`? Same result, uses even more confusing stuff like early binding of default values.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, this did help out a lot. I guess I have to wrap my head around what's being binded to which function in their respective frame. In the main frame f is bounded to h() whereas in another it's binded to g(x)

Comment: Oh, no, I'm wrong, `g` doesn't run soon enough for my `h` definition to get the right `f` as the default. Alas...

Comment: Your variables are named so weirdly and overwritten and re-used - it's almost illegible.

Comment: @11junkyard just follow the standard Python name-binding rules, and remember, *function objects are just objects like any other*, and that a function definition statement is essentially euqivalent to calling the function consrtuctor, which returns a fucntion object, and assigning it to a name, so `def func(): ...` is equivalent to `func = function(....)`. And perhaps more importantly, *there are various local variables* and a global variable all called `f`... note in the global scope, `f` is bound to *three different objects*, being overwritten each time.

Comment: The simplest place to start is `f(g, n)`, so *inside the local scope of the global `f`*, which is referring to teh function created by `def f(f, x):`, there is a local variable (the parameter!) also called `f`.  That is being bound to `g` in the function call `f(g, n)`

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for all these insights again! I also understood where my confusion actually stemmed from, it was the fact that y was defined AND was called at the same time with f as an argument in the last line. I guess it was the way those call expressions were written that had me confused initially

Comment: @LarrytheLlama I didn't give any context to keep the post concise, but this is just a question that's designed specifically to differentiate function from their names and how their bindings can change in different frames. I didn't write this haha

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the names of the functions so that twisted code is easier to follow. We can name then sequentially like `fun_n` and reassign the names after each function definition. I added some comments too

The first one would be

```
n = 7

def fun_1(x):
    n = 8
    return x + 1
f = fun1
```

The second one:

```
def fun_2(x):
    n = 9
    def h():
        return x + 1
    return h
g = fun_2
```

Now we are ready for some bad renaming

```
def fun_3(f, x):
    return f(x + n)
f = fun_3
```

And now...

```
f = f(g, n)
```

which is equivalent to `fun_3(fun2, n)` with `n=7`.
`fun_3` will return `fun_2(7+n)`, again with `n=7`.
`fun_2` will return a closure of h with `x=14`, so it will return a function that returns the result of `14 + 1`. So `f` is now a function that always return `15`

Finally,

```
g = (lambda y: y())(f)
```

creates a lambda function that calls whatever parameter is passed to it, and calls it passing `f` as a parameter. It is equivalent to:

```
fun_4 = lambda y: y()
g = fun_4(f)
```

I don't think it is really useful as an excercise.